# Alguien puede ver el error, no entiendo que esta fallado en mi sentencia WHILE en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Script de mi consulta, no logro encontrar el error en la sintaxis quiero un bucle con los id de la tabla agenda

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if NOT EXISTS tabla1(idAgenda INT);
INSERT INTO tabla1 (SELECT idAgenda FROM agenda);  

SET @contador =(SELECT COUNT(idAgenda)FROM tabla1);

WHILE (@contador > 0) DO 
    SET @id =(SELECT idAgenda FROM tabla1 LIMIT 1);
    SELECT @id;
    DELETE tabla1 WHERE idAgenda=@id;
    SET @contador=(SELECT COUNT(idAgenda)FROM tabla1);
    
END WHILE;
```

[image: Aqui esta el pantallazo del error, por favor ayuda lo mas rapido posible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use While statements only in stored procedures, functions, triggers and events

Puedes usar sentencias While solo en procedimientos almacenados, funciones, desencadenadores y eventos